# Uniform convergence to a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

The problem goes as follows:

> $$\text{Show that if } f_n \text{ uniformly converges to a continuous function } f \text{, then }\\ f_n(x+\frac{1}{n}) \text{ pointwise converges to} f(x) \text{ }\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

---

I know that:
$$ x + \frac{1}{n} \to x \text{ as } n \to \infty \Rightarrow f(x + \frac{1}{n}) \to f(x)\text{ as }n \to \infty $$

I also know that:
$$\text{Since } f_n \text{ uniformly converges to } f, \forall \varepsilon >0 \text{ }\exists N\in\mathbb{N} \text{ such that } \forall x \in D_f, \forall n \ge N\\|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$$

Don't know how to proceed but I haven't used the fact that $ f $ continuous yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the $f_n$ continuous?

Comment: Notice that $|f_n(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)| \leq |f_n(x+\frac{1}{n})-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|$

Comment: Check this: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1933455p13286145

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC it doesn't say, just that $f$ continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$.
By uniform convergence we can find $N$ such that $|f_{n}-f|<\epsilon/2$ for all $n>N$.
By continuity we can find $\delta_{x}$ such that $|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon/2$ for all $y$ satisfying $|x-y|<\delta_x$.
Let $M=\max(N,1/\delta_{x})$.
Then, for all $n>M$,
\begin{align*}
\left|f_{n}(x+1/n)-f(x)\right| &=\left|f_{n}(x+1/n)-f(x+1/n)+f(x+1/n)-f(x)\right|\\
 &\leq\left|f_{n}(x+1/n)-f(x+1/n)\right|+\left|f(x+1/n)-f(x)\right|\\
 &<\epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2=\epsilon.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

It can be proved that if $f_n $ is uniformly convergent to a continiuous function $f.$ Then for every sequence $x_n \to x$ we have $f_n (x_n ) \to f(x) .$
This follows from inequality

$$|f_n (x_n ) - f(x) |\leq |f_n (x_n) - f(x_n) | + |f(x_n ) - f(x) |$$